# Seaborn bar chart on grouped by result on the grouped by categorical column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I want to display the below data on seaborn bar chart and only the grouped data is available.
[image]

I just want to reproduce the same result via seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barplot`:

```
sns.barplot(y=df.index, x=df['vote_count'], orient='h')
```

Output:

[image]